# Can you Fulton enemy characters multiple times?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

If I'm replaying a mission in MGS5 - Phantom Pain, can I extract the same "person" to motherbase multiple times?

For instance, I did the "Hero's Way" mission rambo-style and killed the Spetsnaz Commander,  and I want to extract person in this second run. Will they be saved after completion?

Or does replaying a mession only affecting scores?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you can extract multiple times on replays.  I had done the Broken Wings mission where the main objective is to save a prisoner named `Malak`.  After completing the mission.  I saw that I had a soldier that had died named `Malak`.  I replayed the mission again, and after returning to base I had a fresh new `Malak` ready for duty.

I am not sure if you can have multiples of the **same** character, but I believe that you can get those characters again if they are killed.

As an aside though, I'm not sure if this works for important story based characters as I haven't had any of those die on me.

Answer (score 2):

I say yes, you can.

I kept restarting one particular mission several times for some reason and as a result extracted the same prisoner several times... Numerous instances of him appeared in MB, although named differently, they shared the same appearance and skills, with minor fluctuations in stats.